# Замена слова/подстроки в строке из Dictionary (Regex IgnoreCase?)

Tags: c#

Здравствуйте. Имеется строка, например:

```
string text = "test12345";
```

или

```
string text = "tEsT 12345";
```

ну или

```
string text = "12312TEST123423";
```

и так далее.

Имеется `Dictionary<string, string>`. Например:

```
{
    { "one", "two" },
    { "test", "replaced" }
}
```

Нужно заменить слова в строке, используя правила моего словаря.

**UPDATED:**

Например:

`OneONe Testte ONE словоONe` => `twotwo replacedte two словоtwo`,

`Обычная строкаTEsT` => `Обычная строкаreplaced`,

`OneONE ONEONE oneoneoneoneone` => `twotwo twotwo twotwotwotwotwo`,
...

Слово в словаре - всегда в lowercase. Слово в строке может быть в любом виде, отделяться и не отделяться пробелами, и так далее. Как это можно реализовать?
Пока-что сейчас так:

```
    static readonly Regex re = new Regex(@"\b(\w+)\b", RegexOptions.Compiled);

    private static Dictionary<string, string> _forbiddenWords = new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)
    {
        //словарь
    }

    public static string CheckForbiddenWords(this string message)
    {
        string output = re.Replace(message, match => _forbiddenWords.ContainsKey(match.Groups[1].Value) ? _forbiddenWords[match.Groups[1].Value] : match.Groups[1].Value);
        return output;
    }
```

Но проблема в том, что я ловлю только слова, которые отделяются пробелами.

Comment: Вам надо цифры из строки выделить? Или что надо? Опишите подробно проблему, с вашим нынешним описанием ничего не понятно

Comment: @tym32167, обновил, добавил примеры. обычная замена в строке по key=>value (мой dictionary), только нужно игнорировать регистр

Comment: Поясните, как вот это получилось? `Обычная строкаTEsT => Обычная строкаtwo`

Comment: @tym32167 исправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пишем функцию, которая будет заменять вхождение ключа на значение для одной строки

```
string ReplaceInWord(string word, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    var result = word;

    foreach(var item in dictionary)
    {
        result = Regex.Replace(result, item.Key, item.Value, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Запускаем

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>() 
{
    { "one", "two" },
    { "test", "replaced" }
};

var words = new[] 
{
    "OneONe Testte ONE словоONe", 
    "Обычная строкаTEsT", 
    "OneONE ONEONE oneoneoneoneone"
};

foreach(var word in words)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ReplaceInWord(word, dictionary));
}
```

Получаем вывод

```
twotwo replacedte two словоtwo
Обычная строкаreplaced
twotwo twotwo twotwotwotwotwo
```

Есть ещё другой вариант - без регеспов. Выбирайте какой вам больше подходит под задачу

```
string ReplaceInWord(string word, Dictionary<string, string> dictionary)
{
    var result = word;                      

    foreach(var item in dictionary)
    {
        var ind = result.IndexOf(item.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        while(ind >= 0)         
        {
            var left = result.Substring(0, ind);
            var right = result.Substring(ind + item.Key.Length, result.Length - ind - item.Key.Length);             
            result = left + item.Value + right;

            ind = result.IndexOf(item.Key, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Мне не нужно приводить всю строку к LowerCase().

Comment: @AresGod вы показали, что у вас на входе и что должно быть на выходе. Я код написал в соответствии с тем, что вы запросили.

Comment: смотрите второй пример

Comment: @AresGod поправил на regex

Comment: То что нужно, благодарю.

Comment: @AresGod добавил ещё вариант. Смотрите, выбирайте.

Comment: @tym32167: Хм. А если словарь такой: `{ ["one"] => "two", ["two"] => "three" }`?

Comment: @VladD тогда словарь сам себе противоречит

Comment: @tym32167: Ну почему же противоречит? Я хочу заменить каждое «one» на «two», а «two» — на «three». Например, это может быть простейший пословный переводчик (слова в разных языках могут дублироваться с разным смыслом). То есть из текста «one two five» должен получится, по идее, «two three five».

Comment: @VladD Я понял задачу как `все one должны быть заменены на two`, то есть если в итоговом результате есть `one` - значит что то не так. С вашей постановкой получается немного другая задача, да. Какую из них надо решить автору я хз :)

Comment: @VladD однако, так можно и до `"one"=>"One"` докатиться или до `{ {"one"=>"two"}, {"one1"=>"three"} }`, что уже может вернуть разный результат в зависимости от порядка операций

Comment: @tym32167: Ага, перекрывающиеся паттерны — это интересно. Мне пришёл в голову пример `{ "oo" => "", "ooo" => "X" }` на строке `"oooooo"`. Но ваш пример уже достаточно показателен, да.

Comment: @tym32167: В общем, да, задача недоопределена.

Comment: @VladD а как бы вы решали задачу в вашей версии постановки с пересекающимися паттернами? Мне в голову только приходит какой нить trie с поиском и заменой максимального префикса в строке начиная с позиции i (и двигать i вперед после замены на длину подставленной строки, чтобы не перезаменять замененное).

Comment: @tym32167: Ну я бы составил регулярку из всех ключей, наподобие `^(?:one|two)`, искал бы вхождения и заменял найденное по словарю. Ключи можно, по идее, отсортировать перед склеиванием по длине, чтобы результат был детерминистическим (будет выбираться самый короткий ключ).

Comment: @VladD а если ключ содержит что то, что может быть регуляркой? Например, `[вот]-текст....`

Comment: @tym32167: Для таких случаев подойдёт `Regex.Escape` по идее.